# How can I change from OpenAI to ChatOpenAI in langchain and Flask?

Tags: flask, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

This is an implementation based on langchain and flask and refers to an implementation to be able to stream responses from the OpenAI server in langchain to a page with javascript that can show the streamed response.

I tried all ways to modify the code below to replace the langchain library from openai to chatopenai without success, i upload below both implementations (the one with openai working) and the one chatopenai with error.
thank you to all the community and those who can help me to understand the problem, it would be very helpful if you could also show me how to solve it since I have been trying for days and the error it shows has really no significance.

**Code version with library that works but reports as deprecated:**

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import threading
import queue

from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.callbacks.base import BaseCallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return Response('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Flask Streaming Langchain Example</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
const outputEl = document.getElementById('output');

(async function() {
    try {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        const signal = controller.signal;
        const timeout = 120000; // Imposta il timeout su 120 secondi

        setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), timeout);

        const response = await fetch('/chain', {method: 'POST', signal});
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        let buffer = '';

        while (true) {
            const { done, value } = await reader.read();
            if (done) { break; }

            const text = decoder.decode(value, {stream: true});
            outputEl.innerHTML += text;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();

    </script>
</body>
</html>''', mimetype='text/html')


class ThreadedGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        item = self.queue.get()
        if item is StopIteration: raise item
        return item

    def send(self, data):
        self.queue.put(data)

    def close(self):
        self.queue.put(StopIteration)

class ChainStreamHandler(StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler):
    def __init__(self, gen):
        super().__init__()
        self.gen = gen

    def on_llm_new_token(self, token: str, **kwargs):
        self.gen.send(token)

def llm_thread(g, prompt):
    try:
        llm = OpenAI(
            model_name="gpt-4",
            verbose=True,
            streaming=True,

            callback_manager=BaseCallbackManager([ChainStreamHandler(g)]),
            temperature=0.7,
        )
        llm(prompt)
    finally:
        g.close()


def chain(prompt):
    g = ThreadedGenerator()
    threading.Thread(target=llm_thread, args=(g, prompt)).start()
    return g


@app.route('/chain', methods=['POST'])
def _chain():
    return Response(chain("Create a poem about the meaning of life \n\n"), mimetype='text/plain')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, debug=True)
```

**Version with error (OpenAI replaced with ChatOpenAI)**

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import threading
import queue

from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.callbacks.base import BaseCallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return Response('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Flask Streaming Langchain Example</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
const outputEl = document.getElementById('output');

(async function() {
    try {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        const signal = controller.signal;
        const timeout = 120000; // Imposta il timeout su 120 secondi

        setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), timeout);

        const response = await fetch('/chain', {method: 'POST', signal});
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        let buffer = '';

        while (true) {
            const { done, value } = await reader.read();
            if (done) { break; }

            const text = decoder.decode(value, {stream: true});
            outputEl.innerHTML += text;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();

    </script>
</body>
</html>''', mimetype='text/html')


class ThreadedGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        item = self.queue.get()
        if item is StopIteration: raise item
        return item

    def send(self, data):
        self.queue.put(data)

    def close(self):
        self.queue.put(StopIteration)

class ChainStreamHandler(StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler):
    def __init__(self, gen):
        super().__init__()
        self.gen = gen

    def on_llm_new_token(self, token: str, **kwargs):
        self.gen.send(token)

    def on_chat_model_start(self, token: str):
        print("started")

def llm_thread(g, prompt):
    try:
        llm = ChatOpenAI(
            model_name="gpt-4",
            verbose=True,
            streaming=True,

            callback_manager=BaseCallbackManager([ChainStreamHandler(g)]),
            temperature=0.7,
        )
        llm(prompt)
    finally:
        g.close()


def chain(prompt):
    g = ThreadedGenerator()
    threading.Thread(target=llm_thread, args=(g, prompt)).start()
    return g


@app.route('/chain', methods=['POST'])
def _chain():
    return Response(chain("parlami dei 5 modi di dire in inglese che gli italiani conoscono meno \n\n"), mimetype='text/plain')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, debug=True)
```

Error showing the console at startup and at the time I enter the web page:

```
Error in ChainStreamHandler.on_chat_model_start callback: ChainStreamHandler.on_chat_model_start() got an unexpected keyword argument 'run_id'
Exception in thread Thread-4 (llm_thread):
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Sep/2023 18:09:29] "POST /chain HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user22\Desktop\Work\TESTPROJ\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\callbacks\manager.py", line 300, in _handle_event
    getattr(handler, event_name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user22\Desktop\Work\TESTPROJ\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\callbacks\base.py", line 168, in on_chat_model_start
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: StdOutCallbackHandler does not implement `on_chat_model_start`

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner    
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user22\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\user22\Desktop\Work\TESTPROJ\streamresp.py", line 90, in llm_thread
    llm(prompt)
  File "C:\Users\user22\Desktop\Work\TESTPROJ\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 552, in __call__
    generation = self.generate(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user22\Desktop\Work\TESTPROJ\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 293, in generate
    run_managers = callback_manager.on_chat_model_start(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user22\Desktop\Work\TESTPROJ\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\callbacks\manager.py", line 1112, in on_chat_model_start
    _handle_event(
  File "C:\Users\user22\Desktop\Work\TESTPROJ\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\callbacks\manager.py", line 304, in _handle_event
    message_strings = [get_buffer_string(m) for m in args[1]]
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user22\Desktop\Work\TESTPROJ\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\callbacks\manager.py", line 304, in <listcomp>
    message_strings = [get_buffer_string(m) for m in args[1]]
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user22\Desktop\Work\TESTPROJ\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\schema\messages.py", line 52, in get_buffer_string
    raise ValueError(f"Got unsupported message type: {m}")
ValueError: Got unsupported message type: p
```

thank you very much for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to python273 user on github I've resolved:

```
import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = ""

from flask import Flask, Response, request
import threading
import queue

from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
from langchain.schema import AIMessage, HumanMessage, SystemMessage

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # just for the example, html is included directly, move to .html file
    return Response('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Flask Streaming Langchain Example</title></head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <input name="prompt" value="write a short koan story about seeing beyond"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
        const formEl = document.getElementById('form');
        const outputEl = document.getElementById('output');

        let aborter = new AbortController();
        async function run() {
            aborter.abort();  // cancel previous request
            outputEl.innerText = '';
            aborter = new AbortController();
            const prompt = new FormData(formEl).get('prompt');
            try {
                const response = await fetch(
                    '/chain', {
                        signal: aborter.signal,
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            prompt
                        }),
                    }
                );
                const reader = response.body.getReader();
                const decoder = new TextDecoder();
                while (true) {
                    const { done, value } = await reader.read();
                    if (done) { break; }
                    const decoded = decoder.decode(value, {stream: true});
                    outputEl.innerText += decoded;
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
        run();  // run on initial prompt
        formEl.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            run();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
''', mimetype='text/html')

class ThreadedGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        item = self.queue.get()
        if item is StopIteration: raise item
        return item

    def send(self, data):
        self.queue.put(data)

    def close(self):
        self.queue.put(StopIteration)

class ChainStreamHandler(StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler):
    def __init__(self, gen):
        super().__init__()
        self.gen = gen

    def on_llm_new_token(self, token: str, **kwargs):
        self.gen.send(token)

def llm_thread(g, prompt):
    try:
        chat = ChatOpenAI(
            verbose=True,
            streaming=True,
            callbacks=[ChainStreamHandler(g)],
            temperature=0.7,
        )
        chat([HumanMessage(content=prompt)])
    finally:
        g.close()


def chain(prompt):
    g = ThreadedGenerator()
    threading.Thread(target=llm_thread, args=(g, prompt)).start()
    return g


@app.route('/chain', methods=['POST'])
def _chain():
    return Response(chain(request.json['prompt']), mimetype='text/plain')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, debug=True)
```

Link to the original reply: https://gist.github.com/python273/563177b3ad5b9f74c0f8f3299ec13850

Answer (score 0):

Change you function as below

Old

```
def on_chat_model_start(self, token: str):
    print("started")
```

New

```
def on_chat_model_start(self, serialized: Dict[str, Any], messages: List[List[BaseMessage]], **kwargs: Any):
    print("started")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I really don't know how to implement the previously produced solution with this new implementation, honestly even deleting on_chat_model_start wouldn't change anything for me since the core of the problem is that it would still give error with or without on_chat_model_start function

Comment: if you remove on_chat_model_start what error you are getting.. what is the exact issue ?

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/5Zn77REy) you can see the error that I could not paste as a comment since it is too long for stackoverflow (this version is without the method not useful for my purpose on_chat_model_start).